# Surjective linear transformation of finitely generated free modules and their determinants

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modules

I kind of got stuck on Aluffi Algebra Exercise 6.4 of chapter 6 which is:

Let $F$ be a finitely generated free $R$-module and let $\alpha$ be a linear transformation of $F$. Give an example of an injective $\alpha$ that is not surjective; in fact, prove that $\alpha$ not surjective precisely when $\det(\alpha$) is not a unit.

Here is the proof for $\alpha$ not being surjective iff $det(\alpha$) is not a unit (in $R$):

Since $F$ is a finitely generated free module, $F \cong R^n$ thus $\alpha$ corresponds to a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ thus if $\alpha$ is not surjective, there is no right-inverse for $\alpha$, thus for all linear transformation $\beta \in End_R(F)$, we have $\alpha \circ \beta \neq id$ meaning there is no $n\times n$ matrix $B$ such that $AB = I_n$ which implies $\det$($\alpha \circ \beta)$ = $\det(\alpha)\det(\beta) = \det(A)\det(B) \neq 1$ proves that $\det(\alpha)$ is not a unit. Same line of reasoning gives the converse.

Is my proof correct? And also can anyone give an example of a linear transformation of $F$ that injects but not surjects?

Since I am self-studying, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\alpha$ is surjective, since $\alpha$ is injective, it is bijective and has an inverse $\beta$, $det(\alpha)det(\beta)=1$.

Suppose that $det(\alpha)$ is invertible in the basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$, consider the matrix of cofactors of $\alpha$ $C_{ij})$, the matrix of the inverse of $\alpha$ is ${1\over{det(\alpha)}}(C_{ij}^T)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix

Answer (score 0):

See Tsemo Aristide's answer on the cofactor matrix.

For an example of an injective non-surjective module homomorphism, consider $f(x) = 2x$, $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, which is an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism but is not surjective.